# Visual Studio Test Explorer XUnit issues

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xunit, test-explorer

We've been having a few problems with XUnit Tests and Visual Studio's Test Explorer recently, and just wondering if anyone else has seen anything similar.

Details:

- Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.9.2
- xunit.abstractions version 2.0.3 (latest stable)
- other xunit packages are on 2.4.1 (latest stable)

Things I've tried already:

- We're building all projects in x64 config, but the Default Processor Architecture is definitely set to x64
- Tried deleting a bunch of different files/folders in `%TEMP%` for Visual Studio and Nuget
- Have deleted all xunit folders from `%userprofile%/.nuget/packages`

Sometimes the Test Explorer UI hangs, despite the fact that the Output window says that the test run has finished, but other times it doesn't even update at all:

[image: test explorer screenshot]

This is after running the top test project. I have no idea why only 78 tests have run (I have seen other incorrect numbers though e.g. 124), but the output window confirms that only 78 were found and run. And the main test list isn't updated and just appears as though nothing has happened.

Running the tests using `vstest.console.exe` outside of VS runs all 154 perfectly fine, so I'm pretty confident this is just a Test Explorer / UI issue.